# java.rmi.ServerError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint

Tags: java, jasper-reports, rmi, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with running my server application which registers itself in rmi registry. In `Remote` interface I have method which returns `JasperPrint`. The exception is thrown when server calls:

```
server = (Server)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.rebind("server", server);    // <-----------------------
```

I have `jasperreports-3.7.5.jar` in classpath of the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:393)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at server.ServerImpl.main(ServerImpl.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:409)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:501)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:680)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:669)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:592)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1531)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting rmiregistry with:

`rmiregistry -J-classpath -J"path\to\jasperreports-3.7.5.jar"`

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur because of several reasons, i had this error also several times,
try some refactoring, check your stubs and skeletons are there manually and too many "server" can also create confusion